# IE11Error - Expected identifier, string or number in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11

The JS function I wrote looks like this:

```
function createConversionMappingItemRow(mapType, listObj, className, convValue, convText, currValue, currText) {
        $('#' + listObj).find('tbody')
            .append($('<tr>').attr({ class: className }) // <---- THIS IS LINE 3409, 'c' in 'class:' is the 42nd char
                .append($('<td>').attr({ width: '5%', align: 'center' })
                    .append($('<input>').attr({ type: 'checkbox', onclick: (className == 'header' ? 'checkAllCurrentMapping("' + mapType + '", true)' : 'enableSaveButtons()') })
                    )
                )
                .append($('<td>').attr({ width: '45%', align: 'center' })
                    .append($('<span>').attr({ value: convValue })
                        .text(convText)
                    )
                )
                .append($('<td>').attr({ width: '5%', align: 'center' })
                    .append($('<span>').attr({ class: 'convarrow' })
                        .text('\u21c6')
                    )
                )
                .append($('<td>').attr({ width: '45%', align: 'center' })
                    .append($('<span>').attr({ value: currValue })
                        .text(currText)
                    )
                )
            );
    }
```

The error `Expected identifier, string or number` is in: Line: 3409, Column: 42

Browser: Internet Explorer 11

JQuery Veersion: 1.6.1

Comment: `class` is a JavaScript keyword. Try putting it in quotes: `"class"`

Comment: In IE11, my local changes work fine, but same code in Production does not work in same browser!

Comment: Are you positive the production code was updated? Can't really help you there.

Comment: I have tested above code which uses `class` without quotes in same browser. This code exists in Local and Production. IE11 gives error only for Production.

Comment: Perhaps the production site url has been registered with different settings (e.g. compatibility mode) in the browser. You would be accessing different URL's for production vs local.

Comment: Updated `class` with `"class"`. It worked in IE11.